# Reason for not allowing random access to the vector of edges in adjacency lists

Tags: boost, boost-graph

Why is edge_iterator not an integer_iterator like vertex_iterator? I am using undirected adjacency list with vectors to store both vertices and edges.

Comment: What is an integer_iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjacency lists store a list of adjacencies.

That is, per vertex, it stores a list of adjacent vertices.

That means that vertices can be stored in a single container, but each vertex contains its own (separate) container of adjacencies ("other vertex references").

This should explain: there is **no such thing** as "the edge container", making it impossible to directly address the edges by index or as a single adjacent container.

Note there are other graph models (e.g. [EdgeList](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/EdgeListGraph.html) concept, as modeled by [edge_list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/edge_list.html))

Comment: Thanks a lot @sehe for the explanation. What put me off was something like this `boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS>` where a vector is used as the container for edges. The BGL doc [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html) give more clarification - **The containers used for edge lists must either satisfy the requirements for Sequence or for AssociativeContainer** while **The container must model Sequence or RandomAccessContainer** for _VertexList_.

Comment: Thing is, the Edge container selector is used once per vertex :) Note this is /not/ required when modeling EdgeList, but it is the way adjacency_list<> is designed.

Comment: Apologize as this must be a newbie question, so for adjacency_list representation the edges are stored in a vector of vectors for something like this `boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS>`?

Comment: Yes. In fact, it has two edge lists in that case (one for the normal edge and one for the reverse edge). In general it's cheaper to have undirected graphs than bidirectional ones if applicable. (If you like, implementation details here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25110137/85371)